# same code about string.replace get different result in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, replace

Recently I wrote a simple javascript code, but got a very weird behavior in Firefox and Chrome, code lists bellow:

```js
console.log(
  "sap.ui.widget.Progressbar"
    .replace(/\./g, '/')
    .replace("", "./resources/css/")
);
```

In Chrome (version 69.0.3497.100) I got expected result: "./resources/css/sap/ui/widget/Progressbar", but in Firefox (version 63.0) I get a totally different result: "sap/ui/widget/Progressbar".

Can some explain this? Is it a bug for Firefox? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug in Spidermonkey. It [has been reported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1509768) and will be [fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=9027436&action=diff) in FF 65 if all goes well. (The bug [does not occur](https://bug1509768.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=9027433) on any other Javascript engine)

The problem is that intermediate strings (such as those resulting from calling `String.prototype.replace` on a string literal) more than 24 characters long are represented in Spidermonkey as [*ropes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)), while those 23 or fewer characters long are *not* ropes. Spidermonkey did not properly replace ropes when called with `replace(''`. (see function `BuildFlatRopeReplacement` in [`js/src/builtin/String.cpp`](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/c44fbdd51735/js/src/builtin/String.cpp))

You can reproduce the problem by calling `.replace` and replacing at least one character in a 24+ character string, and then calling `.replace` again with the empty string:

```js
// Run on FF 64 or lower to reproduce:

// Second replacement at the beginning of the string fails:
console.log(
  "a".repeat(24).replace('a', 'b').replace("", "foo")
);

// Works as expected:
console.log(
  "a".repeat(23).replace('a', 'b').replace("", "foo")
);
```